# Google Polymer with firebase: timing

Tags: javascript, web, firebase, polymer, ecmascript-6

I'm writing a polymer app and I'm using firebase as db. I have this code to make a firebase query:

```
let users = document.createElement('firebase-collection');
users.location = document.createElement('iron-meta').byKey('firebaseLocation') + 'users';
console.log(users.data);
```

This code is run twice:

1. In the *attached* method.
2. In a method, that is called, when the user clicks a button on the website.

When the code is run from the *attached* method, then no output is printed and when the user clicks the button, then the correct data is loaded and logged to the console.

Why is that?

Comment: Probably the values from Firebase aren't fetched yet.

Comment: Hi @GlennVandeuren

Yes, indeed. But do you know why and if I can get data synchronously?

Comment: Hi, try to add an observer to your users object, I'm not familiar with ecmascript so I'm not able to provide an example, if you want I can make one without ecma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using a different approach now:

```
<firebase-document
  id="userToConfirmDocument"
  location="[[location]]"
  data="{{userToConfirm}}"></firebase-document>

<template is="dom-if" if="{{isConfirmed(userToConfirm)}}">
</template
```

Now the 'isConfirmed' Method is called, when the data changes -> So I don't have to look for the livecycle... Hope this helps someone :)

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this works ?

```
let users = document.createElement('firebase-collection');
users.location = document.createElement('iron-meta').byKey('firebaseLocation') + 'users';
Object.observe(users, function(changes) {
  console.log(changes);
});
```

Comment: Hi

I'm using a different approach now (see my answer). But thanks anyway :)